# Can not authenticate bugzilla to LDAP with any user but administrator

Tags: ldap, bugzilla

My Bugzilla4 works perfectly.

I am trying to enhance our security, so I have created a special user on our domain called: srv.ldap - It should only have LDAP access, and be used for this reason only.

I tried to replace the user on the LDAP settings in the parameters window, but no matter what I do, I keep getting an error.

I even copy/pasted the domain administrator, and only changed it's name and password: and I get the LDAP connection error.

[image]

- I know that my LDAPBINDDN is correct
- I can connect with my administrator to the LDAP from the bugzilla
- I can connect with an LDAP browser with the srvldap user and the password I have
- I can't connect with ANY other account than administrator (from bugzilla)

Any ideas?

Comment: This [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=pt&fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.support.bugzilla/UIW3KzmlQa8) might help you.

Comment: thanks, not helping. I am ABLE to work with my domain administrator account. I can't with other accounts. Read question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entierly clear

If I understand you correctly. You don not want to use an Admin account for the ldap bind to your ldap server. But using another user fails to bind.

You don't specify what LDAP server you are using. I presume its MS Active Directory becasue of the term "Domain" and "Domain Administrator".

In Active directory you either have to [allow anonymous ldap queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320528) or make sure that the user account you specified has read permission on the part of THE AD where you want to read out information.

You could verify the correctness of your settings outside outside of bugzilla  using ldapsearch from the command line on a Linux machine

anonymous:

```
 ldapsearch -LLL -H ldap://yourdomain.com:389 -b 'dc=int,dc=yourcompanmyname,dc=com' -D 'DOMAINNAME'  '(sAMAccountName=usernametosearchfor)'
```

with credentials:

```
 ldapsearch -LLL -H ldap://yourdomain.com:389 -b 'dc=int,dc=yourcompanmyname,dc=com' -D 'DOMAINNAME\binduser' -W  '(sAMAccountName=usernametosearchfor)'
```